# I am installled auto-import ,github copilot extension,but auto import feature does not work for me

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2010, vscode-extensions, auto-import

[image]

It's my setting.json,auto import not working on my machine
How to implement auto import?? or how to rectify ? is there any alternative solution??